# How to create and set as start page in ExtJs

Tags: extjs

I'm very new to Sencha ExtJs.  I created a Sencha Project in Visual Studio (Ext JS Application and Web API), then selected the directories of where Sencha cmd is saved and the ExtJs SDK.  And I run the project in visual studio where index.html is being the start page.

My question is, what if I want to create a page and set it as the start page?  How do I do this?

Comment: Better you can create your application using sencha CMD. Please refer this [link](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/touch/cmd_app.html)

Comment: yes actually most of the tutorials are said to be created using sencha CMD but we were required to create it in VS, well anyway thanks for the link, and already starting to get a hand on this